# Eden damast knives

Tags: knives

I recently did some research for a couple of knives I'd like to buy to replace the one I have at home, and I've almost decided for the Wusthof classic.
I also found those very affordable knives here:
http://www.knivesandtools.co.uk/en/pt/-eden-classic-damast-3-piece-knife-set.htm#tabbutton3

They look very well made, and I found few reviews, all positive. I wonder if someone of you possesses those and if a comparison to Henckels / Wusthof can be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VG10 based knives (damascus or not), if correctly made and correctly sharpened, can indeed have better edge retention than classic German or French stainless knives, which usually are made of variants of 1.4116 steel (there are exceptions, Henckels marked as 1731, MC63/MC66/MD67, CMV60 are made of more modern steels).

They are also usually harder, potentially trickier to sharpen correctly, and slightly less forgiving of abuse - do not leave wet especially with acidic juices, do not attempt to put in the dishwasher, do not use for prying, be gentle if using tip-pivot techniques, avoid very hard or rough cutting boards.

For brand specifics, referring to what people on knife-related forums have written might be a better idea than polling opinions here.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with the Eden damast series, but I have been using Eden knives for a couple of years now. The steel core of VG10 steel is the same as the damast series and I am very happy with the egde, re-sharpening and overall build quality. 
I have used some Henckels and Wusthof chef knives as well and I would put the quality of the Eden knives at about the same level. Off course there's a wide range of personal preferences, but if you're going for price/performance, I think you can't go wrong with the Eden knives.